# Populate rows (year listing) based on drop down selection MS Excel

Tags: populate, auto-populate

I have a challenge presented to me.
I have searched quite a bit, but I cannot find a solution that exactly works.

I have a drop down listing that represents the number of years (1-50).
I need to populate the number of rows based on the number of years chosen from the drop down listing (1-50).
For example; if a user selects "7", seven rows are populated, and each row corresponds to the next incremental year (populated rows start with current year and ends with drop down selected year.  2023 + 7 = 2030.

Does this make sense?

Suggestions?

Thanks for your help!

Tried MS Excel's VLOOKUP function, INDEX function, VBA modules, etc.
Nothing that I have tried quite works how we want the resulting table to populate.

Comment: This question is [more appropriate for the Super User website](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155488/344380).